# SSIS Package Failed to Validate from SSISDB Integrations Catalog

Tags: sql-server, ssis

On our production server SSIS packages failing from 24th Jan. They used to run fine (in default runtime) until 23rd Jan 2022.

Some reason they execute and validate fine if I run in 32 bit runtime but fails in default runtime.

Environment - SQL Server 2016 Standard Edition.

When a package executes first it fails and reports the following execution status in SQL Agent Job history.

> Executed as user: . Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 13.0.5888.11 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft. All rights reserved.    Started:  11:41:23  Package execution on IS Server failed. Execution ID: 197521, Execution Status:5.  To view the details for the execution, right-click on the Integration Services Catalog, and open the [All Executions] report  Started:  11:41:23  Finished: 11:41:26  Elapsed:  2.235 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.

In SSISDB Catalog execution report there are no details of the issue reported but the status is set to Pending Execution.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GCFi.png]

When validating the package in SSISDB catalog the following error message is displayed.

> A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "validate_package_internal":
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception:
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ISServerProcess.StartProcess(Boolean bSuspendThread)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ServerApi.ValidatePackageInternal(SqlInt64 projectId, SqlInt64 package_id, SqlInt64 versionId, SqlInt64 validationId, SqlString targetEnvironment, SqlInt16 use32BitRuntime)
> . (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

We have performed the following troubleshooting steps to resolve the issue but no luck.

1. Restarted the server
2. Applied Windows updates
3. Applied additional group policy permissions to the user accounts that are running SQL Server, Integration Service and SQL Agent services as per the Microsoft documentation.
4. Uninstalled and reinstalled SQL Server 2016 with Integration Services
5. Deleted and recreated SSISDB catalog

I cannot see anything online related this therefore its proving to be hard to find the problem. Can you please shed some light on this.

Comment: So what happened between the 23rd and the 24th? Code doesn't wear out so *something* changed (before the many changes you've executed to troubleshoot). Were the packages/projects updated? SQL Server patched? Windows updates applied? Active Directory accounts removed, group membership changed, permissions modified?

Comment: @billinkc, thank you for your comment. I am not an expert in Windows administration but I have asked our infrastructure guys to check anything has changed. They confirmed none of the changes were done. However please note the packages were created by an ex colleague and left business in last August and her account was deleted long time ago.

Comment: Let's get the actual text of the failed tasks - `SELECT OM.message, OM.message_type FROM SSISDB.catalog.operation_messages AS OM WHERE OM.operation_id = 197521;`  The 120 message type will be errors but let's see what query generates

Comment: @billinkc, there is no message recorded for the operation_id 197521.

Comment: There should be messages in the `operation_messages` unless you've selected a None level of logging. The reported error identifies the id `Execution ID: 197521`  Fine though, let's confirm that id is at least in the operation view `SELECT * FROM SSISDB.catalog.operations AS O WHERE O.operation_id = 197521;`  If that yields no data, then 1) you don't have permission to view the data 2) you have an overzealous retention period on the SSISDB 3) You're looking on the wrong server

Comment: @billinkc, It's set to "Basic", yes there is data in Operations table. Please see below:197521 200 2022-02-04 11:41:25.9552481 +00:00 20 19 General 5 2022-02-04 11:41:26.1152612 +00:00 NULL 0x0105000000000005150000004865714C693B2D5B73AA7385C6130000 Domain User NULL NULL NULL ServerName MachineName

Answer (score 0):

This phrase jumps out from the error message generated after validating the package in the SSISDB catalog.

- **Access is denied**

Security changes appear to be needed to enable the required access.

Comment: that's what I thought so we looked into Group policies, the accounts were in some but not in others so we added where missing. Currently the NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER, NT SERVICE\MsDtsServer130 and a domain user account are added into following policies: 
1. Log on as a service 
2, Bypass traverse checking 
3. Impersonate a client after authentication
4. Replace a process-level token  
5. Adjust memory quotas for a process

but the jobs and SSIS package validation, deployments are still failing in 64 bit runtime.